# Inserir PHP no CSS em estrutura MVC

Tags: php, css, mvc

Estou tentando adicionar CSS em um arquivo PHP, para depois poder mudar as propriedades desse CSS em um painel administrativo, mas não estou achando a solução para tal, alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu possa fazer?
Na imagem eu estou fazendo as modificações inline , mas quero fazer em um arquivo CSS separado.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Celestino bem vindo. Cara evite postar imagem de código. Clica ai no link de editar da sua pergunta é copia e cola o código mesmo ok

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um arquivo .php que processará o css, basta no início dele colocar o seguinte header

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
```

E nas páginas que irão usar, fazer o seguinte:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="arquivo_do_css.php">
```

O navegador vai interpretar o arquivo como uma folha de estilos, independente da extensão, devido ao cabeçalho e à tag link.